# How to get the time in milliseconds of a store procedure

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures

I have seen many answers, but non of them actually showed how to get milliseconds printed.

I know how to get the DateFrom, how to get the DateTo, but how can I get the difference between them in milliseconds?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What database system? The [tag:sql] tag is for the standard SQL language, but unfortunately, the datetime functions offered by different database systems don't always follow the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand right but, in SQL Server, difference between two dates in milliseconds is:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, DateFrom, DateTo)
```

Comment: Yes, but I still get it in seconds, maybe because the date type shouldn't be datetime?

Comment: I've tried with variables declared as DATETIME, DATETIME2, SMALLDATETIME with values set to: '2014-04-17 00:00', '2014-04-17 00:01' each returned 60000 as expected. It would be helpful if you can show your code or usage.

Answer (score 1):

```
 select datepart(ms, getdate())
```

See:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: `the difference between them in milliseconds` would tend to suggest they're looking for something that involves two dates - and in fact they mention `DateFrom` and `DateTo` in their question.

Comment: Sorry.  Wasn't 100% clear and basically answered the "heading" question.